# Iteratively Adding Item in separate JS file to an HTML/EJS table in rows - Using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a function defined in a file called database.js whenever a certain page is loaded.  An associated page is loginpage.ejs, which starts with a blank table element.

In this function in database.js, I retrieve values from DynamoDB in a loop, parsing each entry using the JSON parse function.

Here is the function.

```
var get_restaurants = function(route_callbck){

        var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
        AWS.config.loadFromPath('./config.json');

        var async = require('async');

        var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
        var params = {
            TableName: "restaurants"
        };
        var count = 0;
        docClient.scan(params).eachPage((err, data, done) => {
            if (data != null) {
                for (let index = 0; index < data.Items.length; index++) {
                    const element = data.Items[index];
                    var str = JSON.stringify(element);                   
                    var x = JSON.parse(str);
                    //var x is the whole item- how do I put this in a table?
                    console.log(x);
                }
            }
            done();
        });
        };
```

I have an ejs file with a table defined as shown. loginpage.ejs

```
<table name="restaurants"></table>
```

So console.log prints each item... but I want to add each item to the table named restaurants in the ejs file. For now I'd simply like to add the whole string to the table- so one entry for each item as I iterate. I can figure out dissecting the JSON later.
I'm not sure how I can place this function in the ejs file perhaps and call it upon loading, or if that will even work the same way? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

maybe, var x = [{no:1, title:'hh', date:'2018-11-2' ..}, {..etc}]. right?

after get data,

in case jquery,

```
$("#restaurants").append(`<tr>
                              <td>no</td>
                              <td>title</td>
                              <td>date</td> 
                          </tr>`)
for(let i = 0; i<x.length; i++){
    $("#restaurants").append(`<tr>
                                  <td>${i}</td> 
                                  <td>${x.title}</td>
                                  <td>${x.date}</td>
                              </tr>`)
}
```

if you use vanila javascript, point is same.

you should control document.dom after get data.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the form you get data in:

```
let restoTable = document.getElementById('restaurants');

var get_restaurants = function(route_callbck){
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    AWS.config.loadFromPath('./config.json');
    var async = require('async');

    var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    var params = {
        TableName: "restaurants"
    };
    docClient.scan(params).eachPage((err, data, done) => {
        if (data != null) {
            for(var index=0; index<data.Items.length; index++) {
                var record = data.Items[index];
                var newRow = restoTable.insertRow(index); //insert new row to the end of a table
                var dataArr = Object.values(record); //convert record to an array, if needed. Perhaps you already have...
                    for(var c=0; c<dataArr.length;c++){
                        var newCell = newRow.insertCell(c); //insert new cell to the end of the row...
                        var newText  = document.createTextNode(dataArr[c]); //...and fill it
                        newCell.appendChild(newText);
                    }
            }
        }
    });
};
```